# A Project Skeleton

Tags: ruby, project

I can't make a project skeleton. TEST_NAME.rb:

```
    require "./lib/NAME.rb"
    require "test/unit"

    class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

      def test_sample
        assert_equal(4, 2+2)
      end

    end
```

gemspec file name NAME.gemspec that will describe our project:

```
    # coding: utf-8
    lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)

    Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
      spec.name          = "NAME"
      spec.version       = '1.0'
      spec.authors       = ["Yanzhe"]
      spec.email         = ["awesomeyanzhe@gmail.com"]
      spec.summary       = %q{About me}
      spec.description   = %q{This page is mainly about me.}
      spec.homepage      = "http://yanzhefeng.com/"
      spec.license       = "MIT"

      spec.files         = ['lib/NAME.rb']
      spec.executables   = ['bin/NAME']
      spec.test_files    = ['tests/test_NAME.rb']
      spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
    end
```

When you are done setting all this up, your directory should look like mine here:

```
    skeleton/
        NAME.gemspec
        Rakefile
        data
        ext/
        tests/
        bin/
            NAME
        doc/
        lib/
            NAME
            NAME.rb
        lib/NAME
        tests/
            test_NAME.rb
```

Any answers is fine

Comment: I figure out the problem thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure the file directories are correct.